# extra data after last expected column in postgres while copy

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I can't figure out why failed.

Here is part of my data in data file lineitem.tbl

```
1|155190|7706|1|17|21168.23|0.04|0.02|N|O|1996-03-13|1996-02-12|1996-03-22|DELIVER IN PERSON|TRUCK|egular courts above the|
1|67310|7311|2|36|45983.16|0.09|0.06|N|O|1996-04-12|1996-02-28|1996-04-20|TAKE BACK RETURN|MAIL|ly final dependencies: slyly bold |
1|63700|3701|3|8|13309.60|0.10|0.02|N|O|1996-01-29|1996-03-05|1996-01-31|TAKE BACK RETURN|REG AIR|riously. regular, express dep|
1|2132|4633|4|28|28955.64|0.09|0.06|N|O|1996-04-21|1996-03-30|1996-05-16|NONE|AIR|lites. fluffily even de|
1|24027|1534|5|24|22824.48|0.10|0.04|N|O|1996-03-30|1996-03-14|1996-04-01|NONE|FOB| pending foxes. slyly re|
1|15635|638|6|32|49620.16|0.07|0.02|N|O|1996-01-30|1996-02-07|1996-02-03|DELIVER IN PERSON|MAIL|arefully slyly ex|
2|106170|1191|1|38|44694.46|0.00|0.05|N|O|1997-01-28|1997-01-14|1997-02-02|TAKE BACK RETURN|RAIL|ven requests. deposits breach a|
3|4297|1798|1|45|54058.05|0.06|0.00|R|F|1994-02-02|1994-01-04|1994-02-23|NONE|AIR|ongside of the furiously brave acco|
```

Here is my aim table

```bash
                   Partitioned table "public.lineitem"
     Column      |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 l_orderkey      | bigint                |           |          |
 l_partkey       | integer               |           |          |
 l_suppkey       | integer               |           |          |
 l_linenumber    | integer               |           |          |
 l_quantity      | double precision      |           |          |
 l_extendedprice | double precision      |           |          |
 l_discount      | double precision      |           |          |
 l_tax           | double precision      |           |          |
 l_returnflag    | character(1)          |           |          |
 l_linestatus    | character(1)          |           |          |
 l_shipdate      | date                  |           |          |
 l_commitdate    | date                  |           |          |
 l_receiptdate   | date                  |           |          |
 l_shipinstruct  | character(25)         |           |          |
 l_shipmode      | character(10)         |           |          |
 l_comment       | character varying(44) |           |          |
```

And I used the follow command in database

```bash
COPY public.lineitem FROM '/tmp/lineitem.tbl' WITH delimiter '|' csv;
```

The error is

```bash
psql: ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

I have done the  following

> - Check Delimiters: Make sure that the "|" character is consistently used as the column delimiter in your data file, and there are no extra or missing delimiters.
> - Data Format: Verify that each field is correctly separated by the "|" character, and there are no missing or extra fields in the data.

I want to know how to fix it.

Comment: This `egular courts above the|`. The ending `|` implies another column/field after the delimiter. Correct you CSV generation to not include `|` at end of each line.

Comment: Or create a dummy (text) column to accept that last | as an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrian Klaver commented, the trailing '|' was the cause of the error. I succeeded after deleting it.

This data was generated by the `TPC-H` dbgen tools. To avoid the trailing delimiter at the end of lines, I found that when we can add the `-DEOL_HANDLING` flag during the dbgen making process.